# React Native Modal crashes app on load

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to create a small request box that pops up from the bottom of the screen to let a user confirm a reservation. A mockup of what that could look like is below. After some research, a modal seemed like the way to go.

[image: Request Mockup]

**The Problem**
Starting the app with a `<Modal />` freezes the app on the home screen. Loading the modal when needed (in the code below) crashes the app with no error.

**Code**
Component rendering the `<Model />` (called as `<RequestTeacherPopup />`)

```
// @flow
import React from 'react'
import { ScrollView, View } from 'react-native'
...

export default class RequestScreen extends React.Component<Props, {nextSeminar: DateTime, teachers: []}> {
  constructor (props: Props) {
    super(props)
    ...

    this.state = {
      nextSeminar: nextSeminar,
      teachers: null,
      requestVisibility: false,
      requestedTeacher: null
    }
  }

  ...

  render () {
    var teacherList = []

    if (this.state.teachers) {
      for (let teacherItem of this.state.teachers) {
        if (teacherItem.key !== this.props.profile.defaultSeminar) {
          let teacher: Teacher = teacherItem.value
          let teacherPic: {uri: string} = ('picture' in teacher) ? { uri: teacher.picture } : null
          teacherList.push(
            <ListItem
              roundAvatar
              avatar={teacherPic}
              onPressRightIcon={
                function () {
                  this.setState({
                    requestVisibility: true,
                    requestedTeacher: teacher
                  })
                }.bind(this)
              }
              key={teacherItem.key}
              title={`${teacher.firstName} ${teacher.lastName}`}
              subtitle={`${teacher.taughtCourses} | Room ${teacher.room}`} />
            )
        }
      }
    }

    return (
      <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
        <ScrollView>
          <List>
            {teacherList}
          </List>
          {
            (this.state.requestVisibility)
            ? (<RequestTeacherPopup
              requestedTeacher={this.state.requestedTeacher}
              onFinish={() => this.setState({ requestVisibility: false })} />)
            : null
          }
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

RequestTeacherPopup Component

```
// @flow

import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View, Image, Text } from 'react-native'
import { Divider, Overlay } from 'react-native-elements'
import Modal from 'react-native-modal'
...

class RequestTeacherPopup extends Component<{isVisible: boolean, requestedTeacher: Teacher, onFinish: () => void}> {

  state = {
    markedDates: this.getDaysInMonth(DateTime.local().month, DateTime.local().year, DISABLED_DAYS),
    calVisiblity: false,
    requestedDate: null,
    requestedDay: null
  }

 ...

  render () {
    return (
      <Modal
        style={Styles.bottomModal}
        isVisible
        onSwipe={this.handleRequest}
        swipeDirection='up' >

      ...

      </Modal>
    )
  }
}
```

The problem still occurs when the `<Modal />` is not passed any children, and I have tried both the built in modal and the react-native-modal package from npm.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Hello while showing or closing any modal,

you have use `setTimeout(()=>{},miliseconds)`

modal is an external window of the screen that covers the whole screen.